# Anti virus integration for Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, anti-virus, malware-removal, anti-malware, malware-detection

Basic, newbie question:

I am preparing to do a new system installation of Windows, and would like to setup Thunderbird for email. Since I am beginning with a clean slate, how should I setup my antivirus and anti malware protection so that: ALL incoming emails get scanned and cleaned for viruses and malware BEFORE I even get to see them in Thunderbird?

Thanks.

P.S. I currently have access to Microsoft Security Essentials and Symantec Endpoint Protection, but I am open to other solutions if they're better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Security Essentials and any other antivirus software with real-time scanning will automatically scan email and attachments you receive in Thunderbird as they are downloaded to your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I currently use Thunderbird, and have Avast! Antivirus running. It easily scans  all my incoming mail, and I have had no issues with it so far.

However, do note that it cannot scan SSL ports.